# Why can't I install this Notepad++ plugin on my older computer?

Tags: installation, plugins, notepad++

I'm trying to install the [nppColdFusion](https://bitbucket.org/bbluemel/nppcoldfusion/downloads) plugin that enables ColdFusion syntax highlighting in Notepad++.

It installed easily on my home computer (Windows Vista, using Notepad++ version 5.8.6). However, when I tried to install it on my work computer (Windows XP, using Notepad++ version 5.9.6.2) I get errors.

Running the installer provided (Install-nppCF.zip) failed, and when I tried to install all the files manually, it seemed to work but as soon as I clicked the "ColdFusion" language option in Notepad++ or opened a file with a ColdFusion extension, it crashed Notepad++. Any ideas?

Comment: I am going to guess the problem is connected to the fact the plugin does not support the newer version of Notepad++ I would verify this fact by installing  the same version on both computers

Comment: @Ramhound - nope, that doesn't seem to be it. I tried reverting my work Notepad++ to a previous version and it still doesn't work

Comment: And now I updated my home version to the newest version, so they're both 5.9.6.2, and it's still working there...

Comment: The .ZIP file shouldn't "fail", as it's not an installer, just compression. If it does fail to open, then the .ZIP file is probably corrupted and you should re-download it.  Which version of the nppColdFusion plug-in are you trying to use?  Have you got the prerequisite sqlLite library/DLL installed/working on the work computer?

Comment: @techie007 - I meant the executable file that's extracted from that zip file. It's supposed to take care of downloading the sqlLite dll for you. Worked on the home computer

Answer (score 1):

Author of nppColdFusion here.

Generally this has been down to putting the database and config file in the `Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\config` folder rather than the `%appdata%\Notepad++\plugins\config`

Alternatively [Plugin Manager 1.0.5](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/482781/topic/4862566) supports doing the full install. (I haven't tried it though).

Interesting that the Install-nppCF script did not work, I have tested it on XP, however as it's your work PC, maybe there's some restrictions stopping it.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with the installation of the "Compare" plugin. The only thing worked, was removing all other plugins, so I am guessing one of the other plug-ins was the culprit.

I am guessing one of the 3 plugins I installed prior to installing "Compare" plugin, was the culprit. I only installed "Combine", "Column sorting" and "Customize Toolbar" before this issue surfaced but I checked and uninstalled all at the same time. 
My money is on either Column sorting or Customize Toolbar.